# SeekBar value isn't actualized in while loop

Tags: java, android-studio, while-loop, android-seekbar, flashlight

I am trying to create a **flashlight app with a strobe** (blink) effect which I can change with a SeekBar (to change the frequency of the strobe).My goal is that I would be able to change the frequency while it's ON (blinking) and if the **Seekbar value goes to 0 the Flash should be ON(without strobe/blinking)**.
**My problem** is that I can turn it ON (with a Switch Btn, but if I increase the frequency once I am **not able to turn OFF the strobe** (but the Flash is still ON without blinking) **with the Seekbar**. If I put the Seekbar value to 0 it's still blinking with the lowest frequency.

**I would be so glad if you could help me.**

Code:
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Camera cam;
Parameters camParams;
boolean hasCam;
int freq;
StroboRunner sr;
Thread t;
SeekBar seekBar;

Switch mySwitch;
SeekBar skBar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mySwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.mySwitch);
    // set the Switch to off
    mySwitch.setChecked(false);
    //now you need a listener to check changes in state
    mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            turnOnOff(isChecked);
        }
    });
    skBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    skBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            freq = progress;
        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    try {
        cam = Camera.open();
        camParams = cam.getParameters();
        cam.startPreview();
        hasCam = true;
    }catch(Exception e){
    }
}
private void turnOnOff(boolean on){
    if(on) {
        if(freq != 0){
            sr = new StroboRunner();
            t = new Thread(sr);
            t.start();
            return;
        }else{
            camParams.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        }
    }else if(!on){
        if(t != null){
            sr.stopRunning = true;
            t =null;
            return;
        }else{
            camParams.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        }
    }
    cam.setParameters(camParams);
    cam.startPreview();
}
private class StroboRunner implements Runnable {
    boolean stopRunning = false;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Camera.Parameters paramsOn = cam.getParameters();
        Camera.Parameters paramsOff = camParams;
        paramsOn.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        paramsOff.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        try {
            while (!stopRunning) {
                cam.setParameters(paramsOn);
                cam.startPreview();
                Thread.sleep((100 - freq)*1);
                cam.setParameters(paramsOff);
                cam.startPreview();
                Thread.sleep((100 - freq)*1);

            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This site is not a debugging service. The code you posted is not the minimum required to show the problem. Please edit your question so it has the *least* amount of code.

Comment: I am sorry for that. I just edited my question, should be okay so.

Comment: How are you attempting to change the value of `freq?` Does your `StroboRunner` class have a setter method for `freq` that you're not showing? Same question applies to `stopRunning`.

Comment: The value of  **freq** is depended on the progress of the Seekbar. I edited my question so you can see the code (StroboRunner and stopRunning). Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I'm not 100 percent sure, but it could be related to the fact that you have 2 variables named `freq` (one in `MainActivity` and one in `StrobeRunner`)

Comment: @Gumbo  Thanks for your answer. But would that really explain why it works partly (when I turn the switch OFF, change progress on Seekbar and turn the switch ON), but doesn't works when I change the Seekbar value while the flash is ON. I short changed my code in the question so that you can see how the things are related to each other.

Comment: @Bohemian forgot to tag you.

Comment: Well, it was actually about the two variables with the same name :P (see my answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out how to fix it. Now it works perfect (Flashlight with Strobe effect, also works when the screen is locked!)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is rather simple but easy to overlook: 
You have two variables named `freq`, one in `StroboRunner` and one in `MainActivity`.

The one in `MainActivity` is always updated when the progress bar changes, but the code inside `StroboRunner` uses the local `freq` variable. And that one is only updated when you turn the strobe on, right after creating a new `StroboRunner` (`sr.freq = freq;`). 
That's why it works again after you turn the strobe off and on again.

If I'm not completely mistaken, you should be able to fix this by just getting rid of the `freq` variable inside the `StroboRunner` class and the line `sr.freq = freq;`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your explanation makes totally sense to me. But unfortunately it still didn't work after I got rid of the `sr.freq = freq;` inside the `Strobo runner` . Do you have any other idea how I could fix that? @Gumbo

Comment: I just tried overlooked the code inside `private class StroboRunner implements Runnable`. There was still `int freq;` (that was why freq wasn't updated (as well when I got rid of `sr.freq = freq;`. So you were totally right with your assumption. The only problem I got now is that if I change the frequency once it never goes back to (no strobe) also if the SeekBar is on 0. I can only turn the light ON (without 0 frequency strobe) if I turn it OFF and then ON again. Do you have any idea how I can fix that? @Gumbo